# Why string name doesn't store a value?

Tags: arrays, string, for-loop, char

when I typed the name to store into string name, but it isn't exists.
I want mix upper and lower letters into one name, Example output: JoHn.

```
        string name = "chez";
        char[] ch = name.ToCharArray();
        string[] name2 = new string[name.Length];
        string letter = "";


        Console.WriteLine("Insert your name");
        name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Insert of letter");
        letter = Console.ReadLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < ch.Length; i++)
        {

            name2[i] = ch[i].ToString();

                if (name2[i] == letter) 
                {
                    name2[i] = letter.Replace(letter, letter.ToUpper());
                }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < name2.Length; i++)// display value from array
        {
            Console.Write(name2[i]);

        }
```

Comment: The line `name = Console.ReadLine();` doesn't do anything to the array `ch`. It just changes what is stored in `name`, and then you never do anything afterward that looks at the string stored in `name`. You don't see any effect of storing the new string because you never do anything that looks for an effect.

Comment: I moved  name = console.ReadLine() to under of string name, then success display name. Thank you very much for help.